# Bootstrap well not aligning text correctly when using pull-left/pull-right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m using bootstrap 3 to draw a well with 3 areas: left area, center area and right area. On each area I will be plotting text, inputing data and using some gryphicons.

I can´t get it vertically or horizontally aligned inside the well. Here is my example code.

```
<div class="well">
    <small class="pull-left">LeftText</small>
    <small>CenterText</small>
    <small class="pull-right">RightText</small>
</div>
```

Check jsfiddle here: [JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cox123456a/498bc/1/)

How can I fix it and make it work with the correct aligments ?

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: I don't know what's result you want. the jsFiddle example looks no problem。 you can attach a picture to show what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
<div class="well">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p class="text-left">LeftText</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p class="text-center">CenterText</p >
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p  class="text-right">RightText</p >
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have updated the fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason why your not using the bootstrap columns?

I would try:

```
  <div class="well">
    <small class="col-xs-4">LeftText</small>
    <small class="col-xs-4">CenterText</small>
    <small class="col-xs-4">RightText</small>
  </div>
```

And in your css:

```
.well {
    text-align: center
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k5yur/

Comment: The centered text does not lineup with floated text.

Comment: Oh yeah I see. Normally I wouldn't use pull-left or pull-right. Will edit it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.well {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.well div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333%;
}

.well-center {
    text-align: center;   
}

.well-right {
    text-align: right;   
}

<div class="well">
    <div class="well-left"><small>LeftText</small></div>
    <div class="well-center"><small>CenterText</small></div>
    <div class="well-right"><small>RightText</small></div>
</div>
```

This any help? http://jsfiddle.net/498bc/11/